# Insert Font Awesome Unicode Symbols in input with Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, unicode, fonts, font-awesome

Iv'e been struggling with this for a while, I'm trying to insert Font Awesome icons to an html text input by clicking a button through javascript. But when the button is clicked what appears is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJvmY.png)

The icon below is showing using the unicode reference but the one on the input isn't.

I leave the code below:

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="fa text form-control an_pf_text anjo_symb_text">

<div class="input-symbols">
   <span id="symbol-heart1" class="symbol-btn">&#xf004</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on("click", "#symbol-heart1", function () {
   insertSymbol('&#xf004;');
});

function insertSymbol(symbol) {
  var textarea = $('.anjo_symb_text')[0];
  var insertStartPoint = textarea.selectionStart;
  var insertEndPoint = textarea.selectionEnd;
  var value = $('.anjo_symb_text').val();
  value = value.slice(0, insertStartPoint) + symbol + value.slice(insertEndPoint);
  $(".anjo_symb_text").val(value);
}
```

CSS

```
input {
    font-family: "FontAwesome", "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
```

I've tried a bunch of different formats of typping the unicode reference, change the css styles of the Font Awesome font-famimly, but I can't get to appears as a icon on the input field.

Is this even possible?

Hope someone can help me out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Adding the characters won't work if you use HTML escapes, because the browser will not interpret the text as HTML.  You can use `String.fromCharCode()` to create a string from a known Unicode (UTF-16) value. Note that when you set the font of your text input to the FontAwesome font, **all** the text in the text input will use that font.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So that will not work with the Font Awesome unicodes right? (My quick test didn't work...) I'm using the Font Awesome to avoid the default unicode symbols because of the browsers converting them to emojis... And I want the symbol as unicode.

Comment: Unicode is unicode; if you  know the code point used by the FontAwesome font for some particular icon, then `String.fromCharCode(0xf004)` will give you a string with that character, and if the font is set to the FontAwesome font it *might* work in your `<input>`; it's not really intended to be used that way of course.

Comment: I was putting the unicode value wrong... Thank you so much! It works just like I wanted

Comment: OK well I'm happy for you, and also that's a good little trick to know.